# Why isn't my include for my nested association not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Gist with relevant code:
https://gist.github.com/iheanyi/aba2eb181b4bc621630b

I've been looking at this for a couple of hours and I'm completely stumped, I'm wondering what the heck is wrong with it. The **Departments** controller works perfectly okay, but I'm not able to get the **Courses** to include Sections in its **JSON response**. Any ideas?

**FIGURED IT OUT.** You can't use belongs_to and has_many in a **serializer,** otherwise belongs_to has higher precedence.

Comment: you get a warning related with a eager load query. Try to remove the line 9 from your `courses_controller.rb`

Comment: I figured it out. You can't have both belongs_to and has_many in a serializer. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out eventually, you can use a belongs_to with a has_many in the serializer, otherwise belongs_to ends up overwriting the has_many. You think they'd keep that information in their docs, but nope. Thanks for the attempt at helping guys. :)